# How do you pull OpenID Claims on Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I've managed to set up microsoft authentication on my Oracle APEX application via Social Sign in. I want to be able to pull profile information such as name,preferred_name,etc which are OpenID claims and display them on my application. I am assuming you would set it in the "Additional User Attributes" in the authentication scheme on the application however I am not sure how it works as everytime I try to set it I'm unable to connect to the application

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please read this blog to set up Microsoft authentication:

https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/1908/

Comment: I followed that to set up the authentication scheme however I don't know how to utilize the supported claims in my application - would it require more than just adding it to the "Additional User Attributes" and "Map Additional User Attributes"?

Answer (score 0):

Go under 'Shared Components' for your app, then 'Authentication Scheme', choose your scheme.

In the PL/SQL code textarea, write a procedure, which assigns values to Apex variables, such as:

```
:app_user := apex_json.get_varchar2('upn');
```

That is in case your claim has a upn for the user name...

Remember to call the procedure by adding the name in the 'Post-Authentication Procedure Name' box.